# Mock testing IDistrubutedCache

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, mocking, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to test a function that uses IDistrubtedMemory cache, I've configured the cache mock object's Get and Set and the Get function seems to be functioning, but when I set a new memory object, it never gets returned. Below is the test

-- Test code

```
        [Fact]
        public async void Can_AddToMonitoring()
        {
            var cacheKey = "Simulator";
            var tList = new List<string>();
            var tNumber = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 6);

            // Setup - Add mock objects that are needed
            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<TSimulatorService>>();
            var mockCache = new Mock<IDistributedCache>();
            mockCache.Setup(cacheMoc => cacheMoc.Get(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Mock.Of<byte[]>);
            mockCache.Setup(cacheMoc => cacheMoc.Set(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<byte[]>(), null));

            var mockEventBus = new Mock<IEventBus>();

            var tSimulationService = new TSimulatorService(mockLogger.Object, mockEventBus.Object, mockCache.Object);
            await tSimulationService.AddToMonitoring(tNumber);

            // Assert - Verify the MemoryCache contains the tag we sent over
            var testTag = await tSimulationService.GetTsForPublish();

            var tSimulations = testTag as TSimulation[] ?? testT.ToArray();
            tSimulations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
            tSimulations.ShouldContain( t => t.TNumber.Equals(tNumber));
        }
```

This is the method I am attempting to test

```
        public async Task AddToMonitoring(string tNumber)
        {
            var cacheList = await GetMonitoredTListFromCache();
            var tList = cacheList.ToList();
            if (!tagList.Contains(tNumber))
                tList.Add(tNumber);

            await _cache.SetStringAsync(tListCacheKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tList));
        }
```

Everything appears to work until I get to the Assert part of the test, when I attempt to pull the object I set, all I get is a null return and i am not entirely sure of why?

Comment: Because it's a mock, and as such is not a cache, so it doesn't have the data that you passed. You're configuring the mock to always return `Mock.Of<byte[]>` so that's what it will return. If you want to validate the method, just validate that `SetStringAsync` was called with the proper arguments

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So to test actual values placed in the cache I would need to move these tests to the integration level and use an actual implementation of the cache correct?

Comment: Yep, that's generally correct

Comment: No worries :) if you want to do integration tests for asp.net core, I'd recommend you to take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0